# Merge dataframes and fill column for every 12 hours based off datetime index pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames:

"df" One has a date time index:

[image]

"df2" has a column of every twelve hours for the same dates and first dataframe:

[image]

I am trying to preserve the 12 hours column, and have the merged dataframe fill values between every 12 hours.

For entire days, it can be merged by creating a column of the days based off index:

```
df2['day'] = df.index.date
```

Then merging the two:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df,
         on = ['day','short_id'],
         how = 'inner')
```

However, i cannot find a workaround for creating a column for every 12hours and filling the data inbetween because this only works for days, not half-days

```
df2['day'] = df.index.date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also easily round datetime columns to sensible frequencies, in this case every 12 hours.

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['2017-07-28 20:17:56','2017-07-28 10:17:56', '2017-07-28 00:17:56']})
test['time'] = pd.to_datetime(test.time)

test.time.dt.round('12h')

0   2017-07-29 00:00:00
1   2017-07-28 12:00:00
2   2017-07-28 00:00:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: So this works, but when i add it into the data frame as a new column: i.e., test['time'] = test.time.dt.round('12h') - it just gives the day and not hours

Comment: That's just for display. All of your dates (especially those above) are being rounded to 00:00:00 since they all occur near midnight, so the display is just dropping unnecessary information. But if you actually select the object with test['time'][0] you should see that it is still being stored as `'2017-07-29 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html).

*If you need help with the parameters: post the code to generate the dataframes so we can replicate your scenario.*